# When dose move constructor and default constructor called

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I have this code

```
class MyString {
    public:
        MyString();
        MyString(const char*);
        MyString(const String&);
        MyString(String&&) noexcept;
        ...
};

String::String()
{
    std::cout << "default construct!" <<std::endl;
}

String::String(const char* cb)
{
    std::cout << "construct with C-char!" <<std::endl;
    ...
}


String::String(const String& str)
{
    std::cout << "copy construct!" <<std::endl;
    ...
}

String::String(String&& str) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "move construct!" <<std::endl;
    ...
}
```

In `main()`

```
MyString s1(MyString("test"));
```

I thought result would be this:

> construct with C-char!       <---- called by MyString("test")
> move construct!              <---- called by s1(...)

But what I get was this:

> construct with C-char!       <---- maybe called by MyString()

The steps what I thought

1. `MyString("test")` construct a rvalue by using the constructor with `char*`
2. Construct s1(*arg*)
3. Because of *arg* is a rvalue, s1 should construct by move constructor
   But I find move constructor won't be called without `std::move`.

Why is that happening?
How to use move constructor without `std::move()`?

Compiler:
Gnu C++ 9.3.0

Comment: I believe copy elision is mandatory in this case.

Comment: @Mechap: only since C++17.

Comment: The concept you're missing is "copy elision". See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization).

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, You can have expected behavior with `-fno-elide-constructor` flag to turn-off that optimization.

Comment: @Jarod42 Only in old versions of the standard where it is just an optimisation. You cannot disable the behaviour in C++17 or later.

Comment: @eerorika: OP tags question as C++11 :-) (I expect `-fno-elide-constructors` to avoid non-mandatory elision in C++17 (as **N**RVO) though, (which is indeed not the OP case which is mandatory)).

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, I didn't check the tags. The option is `-fno-elide-constructors` :)

Comment: @Jarod42: OP tagged the question as C++11 because the example uses move mechanics which weren't available before, so the example is "C++11 and up". To tag the Q C++17, OP would have to be aware that something changed then that affected the example. And tagging the Q C++20 (as in "latest version") would needlessly restrict the audience, so... ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is that happening?

Since C++17: Because `MyString("test")` is a prvalue, and the language says that `s1` is directly initialised from `"test"` in this case.

Before C++17: Because the side effects of move (and copy) constructor are not required/guaranteed to occur which allows the compiler to optimise by not creating the temporary object. This optimisation is called [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), and it's what your compiler did here.

> How to use move constructor without std::move()?

You shouldn't want to use the move constructor. It's better to not create redundant temporary objects. What you've observed is better than what you were expecting.

In cases where you do need `std::move` (which doesn't apply here), you shouldn't want to avoid using it.

As such, the question is analogous to, "How do I make my pipes leak without using the appropriate tool?". 1. You don't want to make your pipes leak, and 2. If you for some reason do, just use the appropriate tool.